# Updating image text programmatically

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup

I made a mistake and renamed some images on my web-server. This has broken a bunch of image sources in my HTML (300 files or so....!). No back-ups unfortunately so this is a problem I need to fix with programming! :)

My previous folder structure was like so :

```
Root Folder
   >directory
     >subdirectory
        >img
          image1.gif
     >subdirectory2
        >img
          image1.gif
   >directory2
     >img
        image1.gif
    ...
```

I have now extracted all images into one folder and prepended the name of all parent folders up until the Root Folder to the name of the image, so we were left with :

```
directory_subdirectory_image1.gif
directory_subdirectory2_image1.gif
directory2_image1.gif
```

all in one folder.

I'd like to remove the "img/" prefix and prepend the name of all folders up until Root Folder to my image src's.

I have attempted to use BeautifulSoup to do this, get all images, I am not able to get this running to prepend the parent folders up until Root Folder:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

do = dir_with_original_files = 'C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\RootFolder'
dm = dir_with_modified_files = 'C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\RootFolderNewImgSrc'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(do):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('~'): #you don't want to process backups
            continue
        original_file = os.path.join(root, f)
        modified_file = os.path.join(dm, mf)
        with open(original_file, 'r') as orig_f, \
            open(modified_file, 'w') as modi_f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_f.read())
            for t in soup.find_all('img'):
              #not sure what to do here - how do I edit the image source to prepend all parent directories?
            # This is where you create your new modified file.
            modi_f.write(soup.prettify().encode(soup.original_encoding))
```

I was just hoping someone could help me edit this to
(a) Run!
(b) Only run on HTML files
(c) Update images srcs within my HTML to have prepended the parent folders of the current HTML file, up until Root Folder.

I think what I have above should be quite close, I'm just missing a little bit of Python knowledge.

This was a lot to take in so I'll put a bounty on this to reward the best answer. Thanks :)

Comment: sorry, what is variable `mf`?  It doesn't appear to be defined before using it in line 12.  is it perhaps a typo, and you meant `f`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is how I might go about doing it. The main point is to update the `soup` object and then write it out. I have added comments at the points where I have made changes. The first part is the same.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

do = dir_with_original_files = 'C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\RootFolder'
dm = dir_with_modified_files = 'C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\RootFolderNewImgSrc'
```

First, if I understand correctly, you only want to work with HTML files, so I changed the condition in the first `for` loop to reflect that. Second, I do not know all the ins and outs of Python paths on Windows (I am assuming you are using a Windows machine), so I gave code variants at places.

I had an alternative idea to write the old HTML files to the modified directory and then overwrite the existing HTML files. These are denoted with "Alternate idea."

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(do):
    for f in files:
        if not f.endswith('.html'): # only work with .html files
            continue
        original_file = os.path.join(root, f)
        modified_file = os.path.join(dm, f)
        with open(original_file, 'r') as orig_f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_f)

#       Alternative idea: write old files to dm
#       Make a backup copy in modified files dir
#       with open(modified_file, 'w') as modi_f:
#           modi_f.write(soup.prettify().encode(soup.original_encoding))

        for t in soup.find_all('img'):                    # Note: soup exists outside of with
            try:
                old_src = t['src']                        # Access src attribute
                image = os.path.split(old_src)[1]         # Get file name
#               Variant:
#               image = old_src.replace('img/','')
                relpath = os.path.relpath(root, do)       # Get relative path from do to root
#               Variant:
#               relpath = root[len(do):]
                folders = relpath.strip('\\').split('\\') # Remove outer slashes, split on folder separator
                new_src = '_'.join(folders.append(image)) # Join folders and image by underscore
                t['src'] = new_src                        # Modify src attribute
            except:                                       # Do nothing if tag does not have src attribute
                pass
        with open(modified_file, 'w') as modi_f:
            modi_f.write(soup.prettify().encode(soup.original_encoding)) 

#       Alternative idea: overwrite original html files
#       with open(original_file, 'w') as orig_f:
#           orig_f.write(soup.prettify().encode(soup.original_encoding))
```

Comment: You can also use regular expressions to substitute backslash characters with underscores.